# ¿porqué el driver de mongodb para nodejs no reconoce proyecciones, pero la consola de mongodb si?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

por alguna razón las proyecciones no son tomadas en cuenta en el driver nativo de mongodb para nodejs no quiere reconocer mis proyecciones, es decir, se trae todos los datos del objeto y no solo los que necesito.

uso la siguiente sintaxis `let myJson = await db(myDB).collection(myCollection).findOne( query , projection )` query es un objeto y projection también

funciona pero me trae todas la propiedades del objeto y no las necesito todas. Probé en la consola interactiva que se instala al instalar mongodb localmente y si funciona al hacer `db.myCollection.findOne( {nombre: "carlos"}, {edad: 1} )` esto si funciona sin problemas

hice una clase para conectarme con mongodb e interactuar con ella, todo funciona bien excepto las proyecciones no sé porqué.

aqui está la clase que creé

```
// aqui van importaciones como require("mongodb") etc
// mongoDB instance
// esta es una instancia de la conexión a mongo, para 
// no tener que estar conectando a cada rato con cada accion CRUD
// ###########################
let INSTANCE;
// ###########################

class MongoServices {
    constructor() {
        this.instance = INSTANCE;
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.client = new MongoClient(URI, mongoClientOptions);
}

async connect(){
    try {
        const client = await this.client.connect();
        // set first connection
        this.instance = client;
        // use INSTANCE for others connections
        INSTANCE = client;
        console.log("db connected");
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
}

async disconnect(){
    try {
        if(this.instance) await this.instance.close();
    } catch (err) {
        return Error(err)
    }
}

// ===================   CRUD   ====================

// ## find ##
getAll(collection, query, projection = null){
    const {instance, dbName} = this;
    return instance.db(dbName).collection(collection).find(query, projection).toArray();    
}

async getOne(collection, query, projection = null){
    const {instance, dbName} = this;
    let busqueda = await instance.db(dbName).collection(collection).findOne(query, projection);
    return busqueda;

    }
}

module.exports = MongoServices;
```

todo funciona bien, no he puesto las demás acciones CRUD porque no hay problemas con ellas. El único problema que tengo hasta ahora es que no me toman en cuenta las proyecciones, no se porqué la verdad.

por ejemplo si hago 
    `let data = await mongo.getOne("users", {nombre: "carlos"}, { edad: 1})`
me trae todo el usuario carlos con todas sus propiedades, y yo solo quiero la edad.

la versión del driver nativo de mongodb que estoy usando es la 3.3.1

no se si es un problema en mi sintaxis o un problema del driver. espero sus respuestas, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la forma en que se usan las proyecciones en el [Driver Nativo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) no es la misma forma en la que se usan en el [Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/index.html) de MongoDB.

Según la documentación del Driver de MongoDB 3.3.x, las [proyecciones](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/tutorials/projections/) para el método `find`, deben usarse de la siguiente forma:

> ```
> // Find some documents
> const collection = db.collection( 'restaurants' );
> collection
>   .find({ 'cuisine' : 'Brazilian' })
>   .project({ 'name' : 1, 'cuisine' : 1 })
>   .toArray(...);
> ```

Por lo tanto debes cambiar tu método `getAll()` para que realice la tarea de la siguiente forma:

```
// ## find ##
getAll(collection, query, projection = null){
    const {instance, dbName} = this;
    return instance.db(dbName).collection(collection).find(query).project(projection).toArray();    
}
```

Para el método `findOne`, las proyecciones deben ser pasadas en un objecto de opciones bajo la clave `projection`. Si consultamos la [documentación](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne) de la API para dicho método podemos leer lo siguiente:

> `projection`: (opcional) Los campos a devolver en la consulta. Objecto con los campos a incluir o excluir (no ambos), {'a':1}

Por lo tanto tu método `findOne` debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
async getOne(collection, query, projection = null){
    const {instance, dbName} = this;
    let busqueda = await instance.db(dbName).collection(collection).findOne(query, {projection: projection});
    return busqueda;
    }
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota:**

La solución fue probada usando Node v12.8.0, mongoDB driver v3.3.1 y MongoDB 4.2.0

Comment: habia leido lo de .project() pero lo estaba usando en .findOne() y no en .find(), no sabía lo de `findOne( query, {projection: myProjection})` si me sirvio, muchas gracias